# How to call a stored procedure with multiple parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How would I go about calling a stored procedure in PHP with several parameters?

let's say I have a stored procedures like this in mysql:

```sql
delimiter //
create procedure createInvoice (inProduct varchar(20), inCost float, inAmount integer)
begin 
.....
.....
.....
end//
delimiter ;
```

Now in PHP I want to call this procedure and set the inProduct, inCost and inAmount variables to values that comes from a form. How would I go about doing this? I've tried setting it up like this but it's not working out.

```php
.....
.....
.....
<?php
if(isset($_POST['invoiceform']) {
 $sp = 'call createInvoice("' . $_POST['product'] . ',' . $_POST['cost'] . ',' . $_POST['amount'] . '")'; 
.....
.....
.....
}
?>
```

So I just wanna know how to formulate the "call"-code in PHP. The rest I know (forms, what to write after the call etc).

UPDATE:
So I have it like this now:

```
if(isset($_POST['invoiceform']) {
 $sp = 'call createInvoice(?,?,?);

$spParameter([$_POST['product], $_POST['cost'], $_POST['amount']; 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($call);
$stmt->bindParam('inProduct', $_POST['product']);
$stmt->bindParam('inCost', $_POST['cost']);
$stmt->bindParam('inAmount', $_POST['amounnt']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I get this error:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in x/x/x/x/x/invoice.php on line x PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => CALL createInvoice(?,?,?) )

UPDATE 2: SOLVED IT:

```
if(isset($_POST['invoiceform']) {
 $sp = 'call createInvoice(?,?,?);

$spParameter([$_POST['product], $_POST['cost'], $_POST['amount']; 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($call);
$stmt->bindParam('inProduct', $_POST['product']);
$stmt->bindParam('inCost', $_POST['cost']);
$stmt->bindParam('inAmount', $_POST['amounnt']);
$stmt->execute($spParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

By what you are currently doing you get a concatenated string like this:

```
call createInvoice("product, cost, amount")
```

Which means you are only passing one parameter, namely the first one.

But what you actually want is this to pass all three individually:

```
call createInvoice("product", "cost", "amount")
```

So you have to add in the quotes accordingly when doing the string concatenation, like so:

```
$sp = "call createInvoice(?, ?, ?)"; 
$spParameter = [$_POST["product"], $_POST["cost"], $_POST["amount"]];
```

Prepare `$sp` then execute with parameters in `$spParameter`.

*Side note:* you are wide open to [SQLinjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: hey, thanks alot. I only wrote the code I need help with. I don't know if it will protect me that much from sql injections but I will add the prepare and bindparameters to the call. I'm slowly learning though, so not sure if it'll work.

Comment: I'm ready to conclude that the source of most of the world's problems is the string-concatenation operator in PHP.

Comment: I ran into another problem. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correct. I updated the post.

Comment: I solved it now. Thanks alot for your help!